# How to validate login form using JavaScript PHP and MariaDb?

Tags: php, javascript, mariadb

I am starting to learn JavaScript today. I want to validate the user login form using JavaScript and MariaDB. I know how to connect to database using PHP, but if I have to do it through JavaScript, is that possible? I

I want to get the user's table using JavaScript. The user will get an error when, of course, their username/password does not match what they have on the database. I am really curious about this.

```
<form name="loginForm" id="loginForm" method="post" action="login.php" onsubmit="return validateLoginForm();">
    Username: <input type="text" name="username">
    Password: <input type="password" name="password"> <br/>
    <input type="submit" name="login" value="Login"/>
</form>
```

If the user click the button, will connect to the table using JavaScript. But I dont know how to do it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I am going to use jquery which is an excellent javascript framework.
Since you have no code to show, I will only post for you pseudo code to show you how you can validate a username and password using jquery,php and mariadb. The mysqli API in php will work with mariadb
**HTML\Client side**

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="jquery-1.X"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(e){
var username=$("#username").val();
var password=$("#password").val();
$("#login").click(function(){
if(username=="" && password=="")
{
alert("username or password is blank");
e.preventDefault();//prevent the form from submitting.
}

})

})
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="loginForm" id="loginForm" method="post" action="login.php">
    Username: <input type="text" name="username" id="username">
    Password: <input type="password" name="password" id="password"> <br/>
    <input type="submit" name="login" id="login" value="Login"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**PHP Side - Login.php**

```
<?php 
include("conn.php");
$username=$_POST['username'];
$password=sha1($_POST['password']); //my passwords are hashed in the database using the sha1

$checklogin="SELECT * FROM users_tbl WHERE Username=? AND Password=?";
$query = $connection->prepare($checklogin);
$query->bind_param("ss",$username,$password);
$query->execute() or die($connection->error);
$count = $query->num_rows;
if($count==1)
   {
    while($row=$query->fetch_assoc)
        {
     $_SESSION['username']=$row['Username'];
    }
header("Location:index.php")
   }
 ?>
```

**PHP Connection File - conn.php**

```
<?php
//connect to database 
$connection = new mysqli("localhost","user","password","mydatabase"); 
if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
    printf("Connection failed: %s\n",mysqli_connect_error());   
    exit(); 
}
?>
```

Please not this is a very basic login script to give you a general understanding. You need to read up on jquery and PHP in detail.